# How to repeat a pattern and modify with a "tab" with sed

Tags: sed

My input looks like this separated by tabs):

```
Yadda yaddabla            blubb_1234          extremlylongtext, with commata
awesomo sappa             dwarf_775           extremlylongbutdifferenttext, with commata
```

The output should be:

```
Yadda yaddabla S23            blubb_1234      1234      extremlylongtext, with commata
awesomo sappa y5            dwarf_775       775       extremlylongbutdifferenttext, with commata
```

So I want to repeat only the Numbers after a "_" character seperated with a tab. Any suggestions? : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/_\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)/_\1\t\1/g'
```

I have shown this with a `\t` indicating a tab in the output. If you're not using GNU sed, you may need to replace it with a literal tab.

Answer (score 0):

awk solution for tab separated file

```
awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";}{$2 = gensub(/_([0-9]+)/,"_\\1\t\\1","g",$2);}1' temp.txt
```

Comment: I think you'll want to set `OFS` to a tab as well.